# Documentum spex record fetch query

Tags: java, documentum

I need to investicate Documentum project to give some clarification to other team.In that i had some clarifications.I am new to this Documentum frame work. I am java developer.

`docbaseSession.getObject(new DfId(objectId));` - It is returing some object. From this object they are fetching all the column names what ever they need. How this method will understand, from which table those values should be fetched. please explain

Answer (score 0):

The table containing column values depends on two things:

1. The type of object returned by `getObject`
2. The specific column being requested (e.g. `r_object_id`)

For instance, if the object is a `dm_folder` object, it will have different columns than a `dm_document` object.  However, since both of these objects inherit from `dm_sysobject` they will have some shared values as well.

To understand how this works, you really need a primer on the Documentum object model, as well as how Documentum stores data in tables (for instance, repeating versus single values, DQL versus SQL).  This is probably outside the scope of this Q & A format.  You should consult the official EMC documentation on these topics for this foundation-level knowledge.  You should specifically look at the DFC and DQL documentation.

A good place to do some additional research is also on http://developer.emc.com.